# Is there any tool for blackbox testing code coverage in Xamarin based project with calabash test

Tags: xamarin, cucumber, xamarin-studio, calabash, calabash-ios

I am looking for tool for blackbox testing code coverage in Xamarin based mobile app project with calabash test?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Is it that while testing with calabash you want to get code coverage? Calabash interacts with the UI and since the app is compiled during test I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible. Calabash interacts with the compiled code so you can not get code coverage when it runs.